# Laravel 5.3 url pass query string but not appearing on calling

Tags: php, laravel

I have grid with multiple column and one of it for me to press the edit button so I can pass the id and on the route I will call the sql and get the relevant values and call the edit view. 
Below is my codes how I pass the id value.

`<td><a href="{{url('/edittestdetails/',{{$test->ID}})}}>Edit</a></td>`. I prefer the url to be `edittestdetails?id=value?` but now nothing is appearing when I call the url the paramereter is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
<a href="{{ url('/edittestdetails/', $test->id) }}>Edit</a>
```

`{{}}` will be converted to the `echo()` clause, so you can't use `{{}}` inside another `{{}}` construction.

Also, property name is `id` by default and not `ID`.

Comment: I tried for other the second slash must be removed. So what changes must I do to my route then ? Cause in there I prepared for edittestdetails?id=value but I am receiving as edittestdetails/1

Comment: @user5313398 in this case you should manually add parameters `"{{ url('/edittestdetails') }}?id=value"` OR `{{ url('/edittestdetails', ['id' => $value]) }}`. The second one will work if you're using a route withour any parameters.

Comment: Ok I have change my route to accept the id Route::get('edittestdetails/{ID}', 'EdiTestController@index'); so which one is better doing this way or the traditional with query string?

Comment: Using `edittestdetails/{id}` is better than `edittestdetails?id=`

Comment: Any reason to this cause I just change to this edittestdetails/{id}

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><a href="{{ url('/edittestdetails/', $test->ID) }}">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: I tried for other the second slash must be removed. So what changes must I do to my route then ?  Cause in there I prepared for edittestdetails?id=value but I am receiving as edittestdetails/1